# How to add a Custom Mailchimp AJAX Newsletter Subscribe Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, javascript, plugin-mailchimp

I want to add a custom Mailchimp AJAX Newsletter Subscribe Form to my WP Blog. I found this tutorial and have followed it: [http://neal.codes/blog/custom-mailchimp-ajax-newsletter-subscribe](http://neal.codes/blog/custom-mailchimp-ajax-newsletter-subscribe/).

I've got the example in working order, but only if I make the **mailchimp-subscribe.php** file a template and then add it as a page in WP Admin. I've then set the AJAX URL as the page URL – is this is the correct method, or is there a more preferred alternative?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm hoping I've included enough information!

Comment: Support for specific plugin is off-topic here. Please consult at related support.

Comment: @Nilambar the question is not regarding a plugin - the linked article describes a custom template implementation. Nonetheless you're probably right; this question would be best addressed to the article's author. danielle-marie, you could improve this question by including more specific information such that readers shouldn't have to read the linked article in order to answer your question. Check out the "[ask]" page in our [help] for some more suggestions regarding the composition of a good question.

Comment: Why not use one of the numerous paid [MailChimp subscribe form](https://mailoptin.io/lead-generation-wordpress/) or the free alternatives available in [WordPress plugin repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins).